# How can I know the position of the selected item of an AutoCompleteTextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have an AutoCompleteTextView. I set its adapter by extending a CursorAdapter.
After selecting an option from the dropdown, I like to know the position of the item, or the item, that was selected. At least, I want an id for fetching more data in Sqlite.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply override the AutoCompleteTextView's OnItemClickedListener to find the `position` of the item in the dropdown list or the SQLite row `id`:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do whatever you want with the position or id
    }
});
```